# Why is Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense not showing any class, method etc information?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, xml-documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio not showing IntelliSense descriptions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500027/visual-studio-not-showing-intellisense-descriptions-anymore)

A most frustrating problem: Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense has suddenly stopped showing class, method etc information in the pop-up, a most useful feature just gone!

I have Googled it and tried the following but nothing works:

[Intellisense doesn't show comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477935/intellisense-doesnt-show-comments)

[How to make Visual Studio intellisense to show the remarks portion of XML comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645744/how-to-make-visual-studio-intellisense-to-show-the-remarks-portion-of-xml-commen)

[Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense Not Working – SOLVED](http://www.haneycodes.net/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-not-working-solved/)

The only thing I can think of is that its a bug with VS2015 Update 2 because the other machine where it does work has VS2015 with no updates installed.

Some examples:

This is what it should show:

[image]

And this is how it goes wrong:

[image]

That's for a class. For a method its similar. What its supposed to show:

[image]

And what its does show:

[image]

Lastly for a for a parameter, what its supposed to show:

[image]

And what it does show:

[image]

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?  Try closing VS and/or rebooting.  Crazy as it sounds, it works many times.

Comment: This problem was just solved an hour ago. See my question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio not showing IntelliSense descriptions anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500027/visual-studio-not-showing-intellisense-descriptions-anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install this one again: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637

Reference is this post from so: [Visual Studio not showing IntelliSense descriptions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500027/visual-studio-not-showing-intellisense-descriptions-anymore?lq=1)

Looks like its the same problem like yours.

Comment: Thanks but this was the first thing I tried which I forgot to mention, Auto list members and Parameter information are both checked but don't seem to make any differences to this problem (for the C# options).

Comment: @VinceJS what about this SO post? Looks like the same problem of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500027/visual-studio-not-showing-intellisense-descriptions-anymore?lq=1

Comment: Yabadabadoo - That worked Andreas A! Installing the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637) did it! If you put it in as a full answer, I will mark it as the answer!

Comment: @VinceJS made an edit to my answer. Glad that it worked.